# Javascript refuses to let me make a string (unexpected character error) Weirdest thing I've ever seen

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

[image]

[image]

When I change to double quotes I'll get an error on the next string I declare.  I've no idea what is going on.

Comment: Where is it allowed to specify a string with `‘’`?

Comment: Please post the code causing this, preferably with a working fiddle as well.

Comment: @MarthyM: Not a fiddle, a Stack Snippet (the `[<>]` toolbar button), so everything is right here on site.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I think it's just auto line breaking by his editor as the syntax highlighting remains normal. The problem here is him using apostrophes instead of single quotation marks.

Comment: yes I'm using textEdit on mac and it's changing all the quotes into non-ASCII characters so I had to uncheck "Use smart quotes and dashes" in my keyboard preferences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use apostrophes (`'`). However, you need to use single quotation marks (`'`). Although this is English grammar and not programming, it describes the difference very well: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/36046/apostrophe-vs-single-quote#36048

On an American keyboard, you can make the single quotation marks using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>"</kbd>.

**Edit:** It seems like OP's text editor replaces quotation marks by non-ascii quotation marks. This problem has been solved [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/120486/quotes-problem-in-mavericks-or-textedit#120488%5D):

> Under System Preferences > Keyboard, you can change the quotation marks.
>
> Go to the 'Text' sub-menu. On the right-hand side of the box, uncheck the "Use smart quotes and dashes" checkbox.

Comment: Thank you!  I'm using textEdit on mac and it's changing all my quotation marks to non-ASCII characters

Comment: Try this: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/120486/quotes-problem-in-mavericks-or-textedit#120488